# Trying to stream in video into opencv from http address

Tags: python, http, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I'm relatively new to this, but here's what I'm trying to do. I have a raspberry zero connected to a raspberry pi camera, and I'm streaming this video from from the raspberry pi wirelessly via uv4l. I use this command:

sudo uv4l -f -k --sched-fifo --mem-lock  --driver raspicam --auto-video_nr --encoding h264 --width 1080 --height 720 --enable-server on

I'm able to access this stream on a web browser by looking at the pi's ip address. Now what I'd like to do is to be able to view the video stream in opencv. This is what I've read works, however I am running into the following error:

```
Streaming http://192.168.1.84:8080/stream
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "videoStream.py", line 17, in <module>
    bytes+=stream.read('1024')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 448, in read
    b = bytearray(amt)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Here is my code. Note I'm running python 3.5 and opencv 3:

```
import cv2
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
import sys

host = "192.168.1.84:8080"
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    host = sys.argv[1]

hoststr = 'http://' + host + '/stream'
print('Streaming ' + hoststr)

stream=urllib.request.urlopen(hoststr)

bytes=''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read('1024')
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow(hoststr,i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue, or if there's perhaps a better approach to viewing this video stream in opencv.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Change

```
bytes=''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read('1024')
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
```

to

```
bytes=b''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
```

and use

```
i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

this worked for me in python 3.5, cv2 version 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I can't really verify your code as I don't have streaming setup with me. But first, I think `stream.read('1024')` should be `stream.read(1024)`. The `1024` is the size of the buffer in bytes, not a string of 1024.

Secondly, `urllib.request.openurl().read()` return a byte object, so your code may later have the decoding problem when it hits the line `np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8)` as `np.fromstring` is expecting `jpg` as a string, but the type of `jpg` is a byte. You will need to convert it to a string like this:

```
np.fromstring(jpg.decode('utf-8'), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: So I tried removing the singles quotes, making the line stream.read(1024), but I get this error:

    File "videoStream.py", line 17, in <module>
        bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    TypeError: must be str, not bytes

So I believe the stream.read requires the single quotes. The code still does not get past this line. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
bytes=''
```

with

```
bytes=bytearray()
```

and

```
bytes+=stream.read('1024')
```

with

```
bytes+=bytearray(stream.read(1024))
```